# VB.NET: Why is "For Each ObjControl In Me.MyPanel.Controls" traversing the objects in the wrong order?

Tags: foreach

Greetings to everybody.

This is my first question in Stackoverflow. :-) I am making a Windows Forms app with VB.NET that puts random numbers in textboxes when I press a button.

Inside a panel object called "MyPanel" I set up 14 textboxes from left to right (i.e. from txtCombinacion1 to txtCombinacion14). When I press a button, I generate a random number for each of these textboxes and put that number in the Text propierty of each one. Quite simple. I access those 14 textboxes with a "For Each" in this way:

```
Dim randomNumber As New Random()
For Each ObjControl In Me.MyPanel.Controls
   ObjControl.Text = randomNumber.Next(1, 4)
Next ObjControl
```

Everything is working fine except for the fact that I have noticed while debugging step by step that those textboxes are populated in the wrong order, first txtCombinacion14, then txtCombinacion13, and finally txtCombinacion1. I expected it would be from 1 to 14, from left to right, so I am quite confused. Why is happening this? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!